# (.Net MVC) How to include variable in the path of returned "View"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

Is there a way to dynamically include the value of a session or class property/variable in the path of the view a controller returns?

E.g. If I have a session variable that stores the current country of the user, can I have the controller return something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return view(Session["country"] + "/Index")
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. For example if `Session["country"] = "~/Views/Foo/Bar"` you could

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var country = (string)Session["country"];
    return View(country + "/Index.cshtml");
}
```

But if this is for localization purposes maybe there are [better ways](http://adamyan.blogspot.com/2010/02/aspnet-mvc-2-localization-complete.html) than creating different views for each country.

Comment: Thanks, that was easier than I expected. I just used country as an easy example, in reality the app needs to return a different view based on the users department. Each department has slightly different displays, so I think this is the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "in the *path* of the returned view," it sounds to me like you're wanting the location on the user's browser to change.  To do this, you wouldn't return a `ViewResult`; rather, you'd need to return a `RedirectResult` that specifies the URL or route you want to redirect to.  The variable could be in the routing data or in the URL that you build.

You can easily create a `RedirectResult` by using the `Redirect` method of `Controller`.